# Possible combination of Dynamic Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have four List of strings. Number of list may be increase or decrease.

- **List1 = 1.1, 1.2**
- **List2 = 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,2.4**
- **List3 = 3.1, 3.2**
- **List4 = 4.1, 4.2**

Number of values in list may be increase or decrease.

**Result should:**

- 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.2, 3.1, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.2, 3.1, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.3, 3.1, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.3, 3.1, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.3, 3.2, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.3, 3.2, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.4, 3.1, 4.1
- 1.1, 2.4, 3.1, 4.2
- 1.1, 2.4, 3.2, 4.1
- .
- .
- .

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking on how to combine the data from the different lists randomly, or...? Remember you have an edit button to improve your question if needed.

Comment: **datalists have a data(list<list<string>>)**
    List<List<string>> combinationlist = new List<List<string>>();
    for (int i = datalists.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    var skip = 1;
    var count = 200;
    for (int m = skip; skip < count; m++)
    {
    foreach (var item in datalists[datalists.Count - 1])
    {
    List<string> combinationdata = new List<string>();
    combinationdata.Add(item);
    for (int j = 0; j < datalists.Count; j++)
    {
    if (j != datalists.Count - 1)
    {

Comment: foreach (var item1 in datalists[j])
    {
    if (j == i)
    {
    combinationdata.Add(datalists[i].Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault());
    count = datalists[i].Count;
    }
    else
    {
    if (count == 20)
    {
    count = 0;
    }
    combinationdata.Add(item1);
    }
    break;
    }
    }
    }
    combinationlist.Add(combinationdata);
    }
    skip = skip + 1;
    }
    }

Comment: i need to make all possible combination between datalist
for example
i have 2 list of string
list1= 1,2,3
list2=7,8,9
possible combination will be
1,7
1,8
1,9
2,7 
2,8 
2,9 
3,7 
3,8 
3,9

Comment: Please don't post that much code in comments. You can [edit] your question and add the code there

Comment: Please add your code to the question using the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

You could on apply `cross join` between the lists and get all posible combinations.

```
var result = 
           (from val1 in List1
            from val2 in List2
            from val3 in List3
            from val4 in List4
            select new double[] {val1,val2,val3,val4}
        ).ToList();
```

In your output if you want to separate each value with `,` use `string.Join` and specify `,` as delimiter.

check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O83lrc)

Comment: its static list.
i want to use this for dynamic tables.
table may be 2 or 3 or 4 or whatever

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by static list?

Comment: mean number of list fixed here mean list1 to list4

Comment: User may be select List1 and List2 only

Comment: Ahh... So you have variable number of lists and you want to apply cross join to them ?

Comment: Yes you understand which i wants

Comment: are you finding solution Hari Prasad?

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = new[]
{
    new List<double> { 1.1, 1.2 },
    new List<double> { 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 },
    new List<double> { 3.1, 3.2 },
    new List<double> { 4.1, 4.2 },
    ...
};            

var output = input.Aggregate((IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>)new[] { new double[0] }, (combos, values) =>
    values.SelectMany(value => combos.Select(combo =>
        combo.Concat(new[] { value }))));

foreach (var combo in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", combination));
}
```